# Solving Optimal Control Problem with Integral Constraint (Insurance Model Application)

Tags: calculus-of-variations, optimal-control

I would like to solve a maximization problem below using optimal control and/or calculus of variations. I'm slightly more familiar with the former but still a beginner who learned from economics books that take a slightly handwavy approach rather than what I'd guess is a more rigorous [normed function space]-based approach that mathematicians would learn. Here goes.

#### Problem

Solve the following problem which can be interpreted as an insurance design problem. You can ignore these interpretations if you want, but if you care: $\pi$ is the premium and $m(s)$ is expenditure in state $s$, $H(s,m(s))$ is health which goes in the second argument of utility, and the first argument of $U$ is monetary component of utility. $w$ is initial wealth.

\begin{align*}
\max_{m(s), \pi} \quad & \int_{t_0}^{t_1} U \left(w - \pi, H\left(s, m(s)\right) \right) f(s)ds \\
\text{s.t} \quad & \pi = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} m(s) f(s)ds
\end{align*}

Assume all functions are smooth and so on.

#### Conjectured Answer

Based on the discrete analogue, I think the necessary condition should come out to be

$$\int_{t_0}^{t_1}U_1\left(w-\pi, H\left(s,m(s)\right)\right)f(s)ds = U_2\left( w-\pi , H\left(s,m(s)\right) \right) H_2(s,m(s)),$$

where subscripts indicate partial derivatives, but I don't quite see how to show it.

#### Attempt to Derive Conjectured Answer

The regular FOC wrt $\pi$ (without any fancy CoV or Control stuff) yields

$$\int_{t_0}^{t_1}U_1\left(w-\pi, H\left(s,m(s)\right)\right)f(s)ds = \lambda, $$
where $\lambda$ is the multiplier for the constraint $\pi = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} m(s) f(s)ds$.

To deal with FOC's regarding $m(s)$, I try to take a control approach. I treat $m(s)$ as a control variable. I then introduce a new state variable $x(s)$ which will play the role of $\int_{t_0}^{s} m(\tau) f(\tau)d\tau$. I thus impose the constraints $x(t_0) = 0$, $x(t_1) = \pi$, and $x'(s) = m(s)$.

Then the Hamiltonian is
$$U\left(w-\pi, H\left(s,m(s)\right)\right) + \mu(s) m(s),$$ and the optimality conditions wrt $m(s)$ and $x(s)$ are respectively

$$U_2\left( w-\pi , H\left(s,m(s)\right) \right) H_2(s,m(s)) = \mu(s),$$

and $\dot{\mu}(s) = 0.$

The latter implies $\mu(s)=\mu$ is constant. In order to get the desired result, I think I need to show $\mu = \lambda$.

I'm not seeing how to do that. Presumably I need to use the initial conditions $x(t_0) = 0$, $x(t_1) = \pi$ but not sure how.

If someone has a totally different approach to solving the problem I'm interested. Thanks!

Comment: you should write $\max_{m,\pi}$ to indicate that $\pi$ is an optimization variable and not a given number.

Comment: Done, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We can eliminate the variable $\pi$ to end up with the maximization of
$$
F(m) = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} U\left( w- \int_{t_0}^{t_1}m(s)f(s)ds, \ H(t,m(t))
\right) f(t)dt.
$$
If $m$ is a maximum then the first derivative of $F$ in direction $h$ is zero,
which amounts to
$$
0 = F'(m)h =\int_{t_0}^{t_1} U_1\left( w- \int_{t_0}^{t_1}m(s)f(s)ds, \ H(t,m(t))
\right) f(t) \cdot\left(- \int_{t_0}^{t_1}h(s)f(s)ds\right) 
dt\\+
\int_{t_0}^{t_1} U_2\left( w- \int_{t_0}^{t_1}m(s)f(s)ds, \ H(t,m(t))
\right) H_2(t,m(t))h(t)f(t)dt.
$$
Let me set
$$
\alpha:=\int_{t_0}^{t_1} U_1\left( w- \int_{t_0}^{t_1}m(s)f(s)ds, \ H(t,m(t))
\right) f(t) dt.
$$
Then we get
$$
0 = -\alpha \int_{t_0}^{t_1}h(t)f(t)dt
+
\int_{t_0}^{t_1} U_2\left( w- \int_{t_0}^{t_1}m(s)f(s)ds, \ H(t,m(t))
\right) H_2(t,m(t))h(t)f(t)dt.
$$
Now $h$ was arbitrary, hence we get
$$
\alpha f(t) = U_2\left( w- \int_{t_0}^{t_1}m(s)f(s)ds, \ H(t,m(t))
\right) H_2(t,m(t)),
$$
which implies with $\pi=\int_{t_0}^{t_1}m(s)f(s)ds$,
$$
\int_{t_0}^{t_1} U_1\left( w- \pi, \ H(s,m(s))\right) f(s) ds \cdot f(t)
=  U_2\left( w- \pi, \ H(t,m(t))
\right) H_2(t,m(t)) ,
$$
which is your equation.
This is not completely rigorous but should give you the general idea.

Comment: I guess I was particularly interested in how to handle constraints without substituting them away but thanks for answer. It makes sense.